# nvd3-community: Series colors when individual bars not colored in multiBarHorizontalChart

Tags: nvd3.js

Using (roughly if not exactly) the same code that worked when I used it with Novus' original nvd3.js, I'm unable to get bars in a multiBarHorizontalChart to use the colors I specify for the series. (The series are the groups indicated by the circles at the top right just above the chart.) Only when I specify the colors of individual bars can I get them to be colored something other than a shade of grey. Has the API changed or is nvd3.js broken in this respect?

I used both the novus-community zip download and a clone of the project yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the bug fixed from [this pull request](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/pull/16).

Try the latest development branch build and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I skimmed the Github comment thread liquidpele referenced. It sounds like I now need to call chart.color(), even though the color is being provided via datum(), as below:

```
    var chart0;
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart0 = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
            .height(123)
            .margin({top: 0, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
            .x(function(d) { return d.label })
            .y(function(d) { return d.value })
            .stacked(true);

        chart0.yAxis
            .axisLabel("ylabel")
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));


        d3.select("svg")
            .datum([{"color": "#133353", "values": [{"value": 1.0, "label": "mydatalabel"}], "key": "mydatakey"}])
            .call(chart0)
            .style({ 'height': 123 });


        chart0.color();

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart0.update);
        return chart0;
     });
```